# Show/Hide button onclick in ng-repeat inside repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I access and show/hide the exact button in second repeat?

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="person in people">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="ticket in tickets">
   <button type="button" ng-if="!ticket.added" ng-click="add(ticket)">+</button>
   <button type="button" ng-if="ticket.added" ng-click="remove(ticket)">-</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

For example I have 3 persons and 4 different tickets. When someone click on button I want to add clicked ticket for that person.

Now when I click on add button, it's adding clicked ticket for all persons :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can have the default tracking like `ng-repeat="person in people" is equivalent to person in people track by $id(person)`. For more depth info visit https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates

Comment: What is the variable "a"?

Comment: sorry, the a is actually a ticket

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure (your question is not too clear) but, maybe you can pass the **person** to your functions too?

Example:

```
$scope.people = [{
        name: 'Jhon Snow',
      tickets: [{
        name: 'ticket1',
        added: false
      }, {
        name: 'ticket2',
        added: false
      }]
    }, {
        name: 'Peter Parker',
      tickets: [{
        name: 'ticket3',
        added: false
      }, {
        name: 'ticket4',
        added: false
      }]
    }];    

    $scope.add = function (ticket) {
        ticket.added = true;      
    }

    $scope.remove = function (ticket) {
        ticket.added = false;
    }
```

And the html:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="person in people">
  {{ person.name}}
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="ticket in person.tickets">
    - {{ ticket.name }}
     <button type="button" ng-if="!ticket.added" ng-click="add(ticket)">+</button>
     <button type="button" ng-if="ticket.added" ng-click="remove(ticket)">-</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can check a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/14749/)

Comment: What I want is: if you click add button it should hide it and show the remove button for the person you wanted to add the ticket.
In my example, when you click on add button for some ticket, it's adding that ticket for all persons. So i want to target only person and ticket that is clicked.

Comment: @MilosPetrovic i just updated the answer (and the example)